# Why am I getting "unused Result which must be used ... Result may be an Err variant, which should be handled" even though I am handling it?

Tags: rust

```
fn main() {
    foo().map_err(|err| println!("{:?}", err));
}

fn foo() -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    Ok(())
}
```

results:

```
warning: unused `std::result::Result` that must be used
 --> src/main.rs:2:5
  |
2 |     foo().map_err(|err| println!("{:?}", err));
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: #[warn(unused_must_use)] on by default
  = note: this `Result` may be an `Err` variant, which should be handled

    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.58s
     Running `target/debug/playground`
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=beta&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ab5084d87397e890a61c4495fc195e22)

Comment: You are "handling" the error returned by `foo()`, but not the error returned by `map_err(...)`.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You're not handling the result, you're mapping the result from one type to another.

```
foo().map_err(|err| println!("{:?}", err));
```

What that line does is call `foo()`, which returns `Result<(), std::io::Error>`. Then `map_err` uses the type returned by your closure (in this case, `()`), and modifies the error type and returns `Result<(), ()>`. This is the result that you are not handling. Since you seem to want to just ignore this result, the simplest thing to do would probably be to call `ok()`.

```
foo().map_err(|err| println!("{:?}", err)).ok();
```

`ok()` converts `Result<T,E>` to `Option<T>`, converting errors to `None`, which you won't get a warning for ignoring.

Alternatively:

```
match foo() {
    Err(e) => println!("{:?}", e),
    _ => ()
}
```

Comment: Or [`foo().unwrap_or_else(|err| println!("{:?}", err))`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap_or_else)