# Coerce anyhow::Error to NjError for node-bindgen

Tags: node.js, rust, async-await, wasm-bindgen, rust-bindgen

I want to wrap a rust function with node-bindgen to return a promise in JavaScript. The function in question returns an `anyhow:Error`.

This is my goofy attempt:

```
#[tokio::main]
#[node_bindgen]
async fn warprometo(offset: u32) -> Result<(), NjError> {
    Ok(crate::api::sync::coin_sync(0, true, offset, move |_height| {
        //
    }, &SYNC_CANCELED)
        .await?)
}
```

This results in:

```
error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `NjError`
   --> hhanh00/zcash-sync/src/nodejs.rs:214:15
    |
214 |         .await?)
    |               ^ the trait `From<anyhow::Error>` is not implemented for `NjError`
    |
    = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
    = help: the following implementations were found:
              <NjError as From<FromUtf8Error>>
              <NjError as From<NapiStatus>>
              <NjError as From<std::str::Utf8Error>>
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, anyhow::Error>>` for `Result<(), NjError>`
```

You can find this current misfire [here](https://github.com/free2z/zcash-sync/blob/7330d360f5ddd9ad826dab3264f69a677078f45f/src/nodejs.rs#L208-L215). Thanks!

**Some references I'm trying to work through to understand things**:

https://docs.rs/anyhow/latest/anyhow/struct.Error.html

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62241599/177293

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53368681/177293

https://github.com/infinyon/node-bindgen/blob/master/examples/promise/src/lib.rs

hrm .. so close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the `async` parts, `crate::api::sync::coin_sync` is returning a `Result<(),anyhow::Error>` and `warprometo` is returning a `Result<(),NjError>`.

The error message is telling you that there is no default conversion from `anyhow::Error` to `NjError`.

The usual solution is to do the conversion yourself, and `Result` provides a method for doing this, `map_err`. The code could wrap the string form of the `anyhow` error into a `NjError::Other` - which would look something like this:

```
#[tokio::main]
#[node_bindgen]
async fn warprometo(offset: u32) -> Result<(), NjError> {
    crate::api::sync::coin_sync(0, true, offset, move |_height| {
        //
    }, &SYNC_CANCELED)
        .await
        .map_err(|e| NjError::Other(format!("{}", e)))
}
```

Comment: brilliant, yes. I had just flailed my way to something very close to this solution

`await.map_err(|err| NjError::Other("Failsky".to_owned()))`

But, you also give me the format of the inner error which was the obvious next question. Thanks!

Comment: now I'm left to ponder the significance of that question mark :D

Comment: ah, I think the `?` actually should be removed? `no method named \`map_err\` found for unit type \`()\` in the current scope`

Comment: @SkylarSaveland yep, I've removed it now.